# Get element by class in JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I try to get all info contained in div class named : `bg_block_info`, but instead i get info for another div class `<div class="bg_block_info pad_20">`  Why i'm getting it wrong ?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.maib.md").get(); 
Elements myin = doc.getElementsByClass("bg_block_info");
```

Answer (score 28):

You can combine and chain selectors to refine your query, e.g.:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.maib.md/").get();
Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("bg_block_info").not(".pad_10").not(".pad_20");
```

Answer (score 12):

That element has *two* classes (notice the space between `bg_block_info` and `pad_20`):

```
<div class="bg_block_info pad_20">
```

So it *does* have the class `bg_block_info` and your code is working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
Elements downloadLinks = dContent.select("a[href]");
Elements pdfLinks = downloadLinks.select("a[data-format$=pdf]");
```

Full reference [jsoup selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you probably might use `Element content = doc.getElementById("pollsstart");` instead `Elements myin = doc.getElementsByClass("bg_block_info");`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use comma between `bg_block_info"` and `"pad_20"`. It should be like this.

`Elements myin = doc.getElementsByClass("div.bg_block_info.pad_20");`