# Extract links from a webpage using JSOUP

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to make a program that shows all the links that have a certain class.

Here there is the HTML:

```
<a id="ig-tu" class="yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail" href="/page-1">
<a id="ig-tu" class="yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail" href="/page-2">
```

My desired result:

```
/page-1
/page-2
```

How can i make it using JSoup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element by class in JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335044/get-element-by-class-in-jsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to get an element (here a **a**)  and his attributes :

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
```

You can also use `Element.hasClass(String className)` to check the element's class.

I guess you can find more directly [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

I hope I help you!